# apache httpd load balancer: glue different balancers together

Tags: apache, load-balancing, httpd.conf

We have two applications appA and appB running each on its own tomcat on two hosts port 8080 and 8081 and an apache failover balancer in front of that. In our setup of the apache the balancers for appA and appB can fail over independently.

But since both apps depend on each other both apps need to be addressed on the same host. So there is no use to balance appA on host1 and appB on host2. And we can not run both apps on a single tomcat, because the tomcat for appA is clustered and the tomcat for appB is not.

Is it possible to glue the balancers for appA and appB together, so that they fail over together if only one app fails?

This is basically our load balancer setup:

```
<Proxy balancer://appA>
    BalancerMember http://host1:8080/appA  retry=30
    BalancerMember http://host2:8080/appA  status=+H retry=0
</Proxy>

   ProxyPass /appA balancer://appA
   ProxyPassReverse /appA balancer://appA

<Proxy balancer://appB>
    BalancerMember http://host1:8081/appB retry=30
    BalancerMember http://host2:8081/appB status=+H retry=0
</Proxy>

   ProxyPass /appB balancer://appB
   ProxyPassReverse /appB balancer://appB
```